# react-native scrollView - scrollToEnd - on Android

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to call a function that will fire upon onFoucs on `TextInput` that will scroll the scrollView all the way down (using `scrollToEnd()`)

so this is my class component

```
class MyCMP extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onInputFocus = this.onInputFocus.bind(this);
  }

  onInputFocus() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.refs.scroll.scrollToEnd();
      console.log('done scrolling');
    }, 1);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ScrollView ref="scroll">
          { /* items */ }
        </ScrollView>
        <TextInput onFocus={this.onInputFocus} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MyCMP;
```

the component above works and it does scroll but it takes a lot of time ... I'm using `setTimeout` because without it its just going down the screen without calculating the keybaord's height so it not scrolling down enough, even when I keep typing (and triggering that focus on the input) it still doesn't scroll all the way down.

I'm dealing with it some good hours now, I did set the `windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustResize` and I did went through some modules like `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` or `react-native-auto-scroll` but none of them really does the work as I need it.

any direction how to make it done the right way would be really appreciated. thanks!

Comment: For this sort of thing, at least for me, it's helpful if you setup a [snack demo](https://snack.expo.io/) or provide the source on github so we can play with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than using a `setTimeout` you use [Keyboard API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard.html#addlistener) of react-native. You add an event listener for keyboard show and then scroll the view to end. You might need to create some logic on which input is focused if you have more than one input in your component but if you only have one you can just do it like the example below.

Another good thing to do is changing your refs to functional ones since string refs are considered as legacy and will be removed in future releases of react. More info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs).

```
class MyCMP extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.scroll = null;
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
  }

  _keyboardDidShow() {
    this.scroll.scrollToEnd();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ScrollView ref={(scroll) => {this.scroll = scroll;}}>
          { /* items */ }
        </ScrollView>
        <TextInput />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MyCMP;
```

Comment: awesome answer, thank you very much. there is just one thing that I don't get why do you use `remove()` in the `componentWillUnmount()` ?

Comment: If you do not remove the listener when component un-mounts the listener will continue to run `this._keyboardDidShow` whenever keyboard shows up. this will lead to an error since `this.scroll` is not going to be defined.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a large dataset React Native docs is telling you to go with FlatList.

To get it to scroll to bottom this is what worked for me

```
<FlatList
  ref={ref => (this.scrollView = ref)}
  onContentSizeChange={() => {
    this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({ animated: true, index: -1 }, 200);
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I am using `ScrollView` since I have very small set of data. I have implemented as you described here, But getting error as soon as screen is loaded -- `Cannot read the property ScrollToEnd of undefined.`