# How to go bottom of the ScrollView as soon as screen is loaded?

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I have ScrollView like follows,

```
render() {
 switch(mode) {
        case 'backNavigation': 
            return(
                <View style={[containerView, backNavigationHeaderView]} >
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => leftAction()}  style={{marginRight: 24}}>
                        <Icons name='backArrow'/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <View style={{width: '81%'}}>
                        <ScrollView
                            contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: 'center'}}
                            horizontal
                            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                            alwaysBounceHorizontal={false}
                            ref={this.setScrollViewRef}
                            onContentSizeChange={() => {
                                if(this.scrollView)
                                this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({ animated: true, index: -1 }, 200);
                              }}
                        >
                            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={[singleTitleStyle]}>{this.renderHeaderTitle(title)}</Text>
                        </ScrollView>
                    </View>
                </View>
            );

}
```

As soon as screen is loaded getting following error,

> Cannot read the property ScrollToEnd of undefined

I tried this [SO Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46791899/react-native-scrollview-scrolltoend-on-android). But it didn't help me.

Can some one help me on this? Thank You.

**Edit 1**
This is how I set the reference

```
setScrollViewRef(element) {
    this.scrollView = element;
}
```

Comment: Try `this.setScrollViewRef.scrollToEnd` instead of `this.scrollView`

Comment: infact, `setScrollViewRef` is a function where I am  assigning `ref` to `this.scrollView`

Comment: Got it, can you show me that function?

Comment: Please check my edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use React.createRef()

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.scrollView = React.createRef();
}
render() {
  <ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: 'center'}}
    horizontal
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    alwaysBounceHorizontal={false}
    ref={this.scrollView}
    onContentSizeChange={() => {
      if(this.scrollView)
      this.scrollView.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true, index: -1 }, 200);
    }}>
  </ScrollView>
}
```

Comment: Awesome...it's working...May I know what does this statement mean -- `this.scrollView = React.createRef()`

Comment: from my understanding it is new and safe way to store reference in react.  it prevents from null and undefined refs. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: BTW, what is `current` in `this.scrollView.current` ?  And what does `index -1` do?

Comment: current is reference of scrollview, and index -1, 200 is actually unnecessary here. you can just use this.scrollView.current.scrollToEnd({animated: true})

Comment: isn't `this.scrollView` alone enough as a reference to `scrollView`? Is `current' specific to `scrollView`?

Comment: .current isn't specific to scrollView. it is specific to how React.createRef works. it stores reference to .current

Comment: Great, Thank You so  much for the explanation.

Comment: @is this way of using `refs` only for `react-native` components? let's say there is `<CalendarList />`  component from `react-native-calendars`. Can we use same type of `refs` usage for such a external library components also?